# Получить значение с Inline клавиатуры telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="question")
async def question(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    answer = call.data
    if answer == "Да":
        await call.message.answer(text="Парсинг займет 1 минуту, ожидайте...", show_alert=True)
    else:
        await call.message.answer(text="Отменено.", show_alert=True)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['parse_channels'])

async def question(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Вы точно хотите начать парсинг новых каналов?", reply_markup=kb.keyboard)
```

***Файл keyboards.py***

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="question"))   
keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="question"))
```

Вопрос в следующем: как по нажатию инлайн кнопки со значением "Да" отправить соответсвующее сообщение? С чем сравнивать?

Comment: `call.data` это то, что вы передали в `callback_data` при создании кнопки. Просто передавайте (например) в случае *да* - *1*, *нет* - *0* и сравниваете вместо `if answer == "Да":` - `if answer == "1":`

Comment: ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['new_channels'])

async def parse_confirm(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Вы точно хотите начать парсинг новых каналов?", reply_markup=kb.question)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda y: y.data == "1")
async def answer_yes(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, '✅ Парсинг займет 1-2 минуты, ожидайте...')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda n: n.data == "0")
async def answer_no(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, '❌ Отменено')
```

Проблема решена.

Файл keyboards.py

```
question = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
question.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="1"))   
question.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="0"))
```